# How to send the authentication header info?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

I am trying to access the Java service using the WCF approach where i added the service reference to the solution. The service is a JAVA service hosted in a WAS server. The request sent is the following information,

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:wsa="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
<soap:Header>
    <VisSvcHeaders xmlns="http://dai.e.VisSvc/2010/svc">
        <packNGo>false</packNGo>
    </VisSvcHeaders>
    <wsa:Action>http://vissvc.e.com/2010/svc/getData</wsa:Action>
    <wsa:From>
        <wsa:Address>Vis</wsa:Address>
    </wsa:From>
    <wsa:MessageID>urn:uuid:6e1fd026-99cf-4abf-90f0-35f7803aa624</wsa:MessageID>
    <wsa:ReplyTo>
        <wsa:Address>http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing/role/anonymous</wsa:Address>
    </wsa:ReplyTo>
    <wsa:To>https://vissvc.e.intra.net/VisSvcNative/Service</wsa:To>
    <wsse:Security>
        <wsu:Timestamp wsu:Id="Timestamp-79d3f408-1f2b-45c9-a04c-448a3ceb6afe">
            <wsu:Created>2014-02-14T06:13:44Z</wsu:Created>
            <wsu:Expires>2014-02-14T06:18:44Z</wsu:Expires>
        </wsu:Timestamp>
    </wsse:Security>
</soap:Header>
```

the front end code snippet is

```
using (ServiceReference1.ServicePortTypeClient svc = new ServiceReference1.VisServicePortTypeClient())
        {
            svc.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = "username";
            svc.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = "password";               
            ServiceReference1.ResponseType response = svc.getData();   
            Console.WriteLine("Connected");
        }
```

the app.config file is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
<appSettings>
<add key="WebServiceUrl" value="https://vissvc.e.intra.net/VisSvcNative/Servic"/>
<add key="LogoutUrl" value="http://login.e.corpintra.net/internal/logout"/>
</appSettings>
<system.net>
<defaultProxy >
<proxy autoDetect ="True" />
</defaultProxy>
</system.net>
<system.serviceModel>
  <bindings>
    <basicHttpBinding>
      <binding>
        <security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential">
          <transport clientCredentialType="None" realm="VisService.intra"/>
          <message clientCredentialType="UserName" />
        </security>
      </binding>
      <binding name="VisSoapBinding" >    
      </binding>
    </basicHttpBinding>
   <client>
        <endpoint address="https://vissvc.e.intra.net/VisSvcNative/Servic"
            binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="VisSoapBinding"
            contract="ServiceReference1.VisServicePortType" name="VisServicePort" />
    </client>
    </system.diagnostics>
    </configuration>
```

i always get an error
"The HTTP request is unauthorized with client authentication scheme 'Anonymous'. The authentication header received from the server was 'basic realm="VisService.intra./VisSvcNative"'". Whatever I change the security mode i am getting the same error.
Please help me in this.

I am using .net c# 4.0

Comment: Try sending header as in the solution below

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3734074/send-information-in-soap-header-to-wcf-service-in-c-sharp

Comment: @ smilu- I have just created a console application and trying to add the reference and access it. How can I use this in my solution?

Comment: @ smilu - I was able to achieve this by doing some modifications in the app.config file which i got it from our clients. thanks for the help.